# Does Mail::Box::Manager handle Qmail maildir format?

Tags: perl, email, perl-module, maildir

It's not obvious which format this module supports. No mention of 'qmail' nor 'maildir'.

http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box-2.120/lib/Mail/Box/Manager.pod

It has functions to move between folders, which sounds like maildir, but then it also hints that it encapsulates  Mail::Box::Mbox, which sounds like the single file mbox format.

Here is a description of maildir format: http://wiki.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir, and description of both: http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html

Answer (score 1):

http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box-2.120/lib/Mail/Box-Overview.pod

> Each folder maintains a list of messages. Much effort is made to hide differences between folder types and kinds of messages. Your program can be used for MBOX, MH, Maildir, and POP3 folders with no change at all (as long as you stick to the rules).